# Bluetooth keyboard disconnecting, requires re-pairing to connect again

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth

So I got a Bluetooth keyboard a few weeks ago and it's not too bad for the price I got it at, but it's got one major flaw. After leaving it for ~30 minutes my laptop forgets about it. It doesn't reconnect unless I go into the Bluetooth settings and remove it then pair it again. The same thing happens when I restart my laptop. I don't really see the point in using it if I have to do this every time I turn my laptop on. Sometimes it re-pairs immediately, other times it gives me five or so "enter the keyboard's password" then "your keyboard stopped waiting" errors. How do I have it automatically find my laptop and connect, or at least shorten this process so I don't have to take ten minutes to get the keyboard working every single restart.

Answer (score 0):

Windows' behavior towards Bluetooth devices is somewhat standard. If you have things losing their connection, there are two places you can look:

- The Bluetooth radio on your laptop
- The actual device

Unfortunately this is a common problem with cheaper bluetooth devices. Not just keyboards.. headsets, mice, etc.

What I'd try, in order, is something like this:

1. Ensure you have up-to-date drivers for the Bluetooth module in your laptop.
2. If there's a driver that's specific to the laptop (provided by the manufacturer), try installing that even if it's older than the one that Windows finds by default.
3. Try an external Bluetooth dongle. *DO NOT* buy the cheapest one you can find, as you're likely to have the same problem. Read the reviews carefully :)
4. Barring all that - the device is probably faulty.

Good luck!